# Tomcat with Spring

Tags: spring, tomcat

I have a 3-tier application hosted in Tomcat; web, service and DAO layers.

How do you integrate Tomcat and Spring? I need to make use of Spring's dependency injection, transaction management, etc.

I can only think of instantiating a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext but this way the ApplicationContext singleton instance is not visible across layers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are creating web application you don't use `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`. Instead of that you use features of web-container.

You define application context in `web.xml`.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

For details take a look into documentation [Convenient ApplicationContext instantiation for web applications](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-create).

If a bean needs instance of application context, use `ApplicationContextAware` interface.