# Using spring core functionalities in tomcat based jersey application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I want to use spring's dependency injection for now(other core functionalites later maybe) in tomcat application.

I want to set up spring 2.5.5 in tomcat7, But don't have clarity on how to do this.

Specifically I am confused because I don't know whether to use Spring MVC or use just spring in tomcat.

I found this question helpful: [Tomcat with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066971/tomcat-with-spring), But still didn't get the whole scenario on how to setup tomcat with spring.

Comment: your question is not as per SO guidelines, answers to your question would be kind of suggestion.. so my suggestion--> I think you need a good Spring book!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do either, using just core spring with tomcat is fine. MVC provides additional [functionality](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html).

Take a look at the spring source examples on github, and read their docs.

(BTW I thouroughy spring-MVC component - it really saves time developing webapps)